# How is a theme template file picked up?

Tags: theming, 8

Does any one know how Drupal 8 picks up theme template file? I mean in source code.

I have module which use a custom template file for a custom block , but the custom template file was not been picked up.

I have tried many different ways, but none working, so I have decided to looking Drupal 8 source code to find out , but I am unable to find out exact source code that picks up the theme template file.

Comment: Have you added a theme hook?

Comment: Please check the values on render array that you return from your hook_theme, make sure the twig file is inside the /templates directory of you r module, and flush cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have just uninstall / re install the module, now it worked.
Drupal 8, probably keep some old information somewhere in cache.

By the way, during debuging, I have found this interesting class:

Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and tried:

```
{% include 'my-template.html.twig' %}
{% include directory ~ '/templates/my-template.html.twig' %}
```

but ThemeRegistryLoader wouldn't recognize 'my-template'. This syntax worked:

```
{% include 'modules/custom/my_module/templates/my-template.html.twig' %}
```